# Joining after transposing with condition - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "initial" formatted like the following:

| id | category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Bob |
| 1 | Count | 102 |
| 1 | Serial | 123ABC |
| 2 | Name | Mary |
| 2 | Serial | 234BCD |
| 3 | Serial | 345CDE |

A table "serials":

| serial | color |
| --- | --- |
| 123ABC | Blue |
| 234BCD | Red |
| 345CDE | Blue |

And a table 'users':

| id | priority |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | High |
| 2 | Medium |
| 3 | Low |

I transpose the "initial" using the following using the following query, then try to join on "serial":

```
SELECT
MAX(CASE WHEN initial.category = 'Name' THEN initial.value END) 'Name', 
MAX(CASE WHEN initial.category = 'Count' THEN initial.value END) 'Count', 
MAX(CASE WHEN initial.category = 'Serial' THEN initial.value END) 'Serial', 
serials.color
FROM initial
LEFT JOIN users on users.id = initial.id
LEFT JOIN serials on serials.serial = initial.value
```

When I do this, it cannot properly join on 'serial' if there are other entries of the same id preceding it. I tried

```
LEFT JOIN serials on serials.serial = initial.value and initial.category = "Serial"
```

but it did not do anything. If I add the `and initial.category = "Serial"` to the first join:

`LEFT JOIN users on users.id = initial.id and initial.category = "Serial"`

I can then successfully get the 'color,' but no longer get the other category values. How would I be able to successfully join onto the serials table?

Expected results:

| id | Name | Count | Serial | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 102 | 123ABC | Blue |
| 2 | Mary |  | 234BCD | Red |
| 3 |  |  | 345CDE | Blue |

Actual ('Color' isn't pulled from ids 1 and 2 because initial.value refers to the first entry of each id, in this case 'Name' "Bob" and "Mary" while for id 3, it refers to 'Serial' "345CDE":

| id | Name | Count | Serial | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 102 | 123ABC |  |
| 2 | Mary |  | 234BCD |  |
| 3 |  |  | 345CDE | Blue |

I thought of creating a temporary table, but due to access permissions I am unable to create any tables/views

Comment: Not sure why the second and third tables aren't working, they look fine on the preview

Comment: Added expected results and fixed formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform transposing as a subquery, and then do your joins:

```
SELECT 
   inpvtd.id,
   inpvtd.'Name',
   inpvtd.'Count',
   inpvtd.'Serial',
   s.Color

FROM (
    SELECT
      init.id,
      MAX(CASE WHEN init.category = 'Name' THEN init.value END) 'Name', 
      MAX(CASE WHEN init.category = 'Count' THEN init.value END) 'Count', 
      MAX(CASE WHEN init.category = 'Serial' THEN init.value END) 'Serial'
    FROM initial init
    GROUP BY 
      init.id
    ) inpvtd
   
  LEFT JOIN users u
  on u.id = inpvtd.id

  LEFT JOIN serials s
  on s.serial = inpvtd.Serial
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you!